# separate files Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying separate my own services and controllers. I think I've done something wrong however because I continue to get the unknown provider error. This is my code for my app including service and controller.

TaskServices :

```
app = angular.module('TaskApp',[]);
app.factory('Tasks', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.service('tasks');
});
```

TaskControllers :

```
app = angular.module('TaskApp',[]);
//Task controller
app.controller('TaskCtrl',['Tasks', function($scope, Restangular, Tasks) {
  // loading data
  Tasks.getList().then(function(tasks){
    $scope.tasks = tasks;
  });
}]);
// Create new patient controller
app.controller('CreateTaskCtrl', function($scope, Restangular) {
});
```

Comment: don't you have to include 'Tasks' as a dependency in your controller?

Comment: @Jax700303 I include tasks

Comment: also don't think 'Restangular' should be a dependency in your controller

Comment: Seems OK - http://plnkr.co/edit/nttb5B1TEEiM1BrB6R1c?p=preview. However, some errors have been pointed out in the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

you are defining module with same name at both places

```
TaskServices :
app = angular.module('TaskApp',[]);


TaskControllers :
app = angular.module('TaskApp',[]);
```

where as actually you should define it in one place, and just get it in another... `app = angular.module('TaskApp');`

Comment: Correct. See reference: "Creation versus Retrieval" https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Answer (score 0):

You should to inject your dependencies as the should be injected in the second parameter of your `controller`s definition.

I mean the next:

```
app.controller('TaskCtrl',['Tasks', function($scope, Restangular, Tasks)
```

will not work because of angular tries to inject only `Tasks` dependency, it does not know about `Restangular` and `Tasks`. After minification of the code above your `$scope` variable will be in the real a `Tasks` service.

Right syntax is next:

```
app.controller('TaskCtrl',[
  '$scope', 
  'Restangular', 
  'Tasks', 
  function($scope, Restangular, Tasks) {
    // code goes here
  }
]};
```

You should to inject your dependencies always as they go by the order.